# Why does the if statement get bypassed?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to figure out why the second string of "peptide_seq" bypasses the first `if` statement? The three strings are supposed to go through the `if` statements and return the following statements:

> Convert the string to uppercase.
>
> - Strings that contain any character that is not A C G T or U should return: "not an unambiguous nucleotide".
> - Strings that contain ACGU should return "DNA".
> - Strings that contain ACGT should return "RNA".

```
def nuc_ac_check(string):
    input_string = string.upper()

    if ('d') in input_string:
        return "not an unambiguous nucleic acid"
    elif ('A' and 'C' and 'G' and 'U') in input_string:
        return "Rna"
    elif ('A' and 'C' and 'G' and 'T') in input_string:
        return "Dna"

Rna_seq = "GGUACGGCUUGGUAUCCCACUCAGUGGCACCUGUGGCCU"
peptide_seq= "acgsdtushnsdses"
Dna_seq = "ggatacgatc"

print ('the rna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Rna_seq))
print ('the peptide seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(peptide_seq))
print ('the Dna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Dna_seq))
```

Comment: `input_string = string.upper()` you turned everything to upper. of course `'d'` will never hit...

Comment: Note that `('A' and 'C' and 'G' and 'U')` is simply `'U'`, which I guess is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

First condition should be fixed in following way:

```
 if ('D') in input_string:
    return "not an unambigious nucleic acid"
```

Notice the upper case 'D' in the condition.

**Update:**
Full code, using Holloway and rassar comments:
**Update 1:**
Full code, using Holloway and rassar, and Copperfield comments:

```
def nuc_ac_check(string):
    input_string = string.upper()

    rna_letter = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'U']
    dna_letter = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']

    if ('D') in input_string:
        return "not an unambigious nucleic acid"
    elif all(letter in rna_letter for letter in input_string):
        return "Rna"
    elif all(letter in dna_letter for letter in input_string):
        return "Dna"
    return "Nothing of everything above"

Rna_seq = "GGUACGGCUUGGUAUCCCACUCAGUGGCACCUGUGGCCU"
peptide_seq= "acgsdtushnsdses"
Dna_seq = "ggatacgatc"
weird_string = "AGCTEXF"

print ('the rna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Rna_seq))
print ('the peptide seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(peptide_seq))
print ('the Dna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Dna_seq))
print ('the weird string variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(weird_string))
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thanks so much!!

Comment: this can't rule out "AGCTEXF" for example, it would incorrectly mark it as dna

Comment: @Copperfield, code is fixed. It is not an optimal way, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say:

```
elif ('A' and 'C' and 'G' and 'T') in input_string:
```

You have to say:

```
elif 'A' in input_string and 'C' in input_string and 'G' in input_string and 'T' in input_string:
```

Or you could make it more concise:

```
elif all(letter in input_string for letter in ('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')):
```

So try this:

```
if all(letter in input_string for letter in ('A', 'C', 'G', 'U')):
    return "Rna"
elif all(letter in input_string for letter in ('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')):
    return "Dna"
else:
    return "not an unambiguous nucleic acid"
```

Comment: cleaner to use `all(letter in input_string for letter in ('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'))`

Comment: @Holloway thanks...didn't know about that function :)

Comment: If I was to say any letter in the first statment except A C G T U would it look like this:  if all(letter in input_string for letter in ('B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J','K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q','R', 'S', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )):
        return "not an unambigious nucleic acid"

Comment: ah it didnt. I used "any" and it worked. Thank you rassar and Holloway

Answer (score 0):

.upper() will convert everything in the UPPERCASE. And other conditions like  `('A' and 'C' and 'G' and 'T')` will always give the one char, so you need to update the if clauses. 
You should try something like this.

```
def containsAny(seq, aset):
    """ Check whether sequence seq contains ANY of the items in aset. """
    for c in seq:
        if c in aset: return True
    return False

def nuc_ac_check(string):
    input_string = string.upper() # update it as per your need

    if ('d') in input_string:
        return "not an unambigious nucleic acid"
    elif containsAny(input_string,['A','C','G','U']):
        return "Rna"
    elif containsAny(input_string,['A','C','G','T']):
        return "Dna"

Rna_seq = "GGUACGGCUUGGUAUCCCACUCAGUGGCACCUGUGGCCU" peptide_seq= "acgsdtushnsdses" Dna_seq = "ggatacgatc"

print ('the rna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Rna_seq)) print ('the peptide seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(peptide_seq)) print ('the Dna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Dna_seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do, but this may do the job:

```
dna_set = set("ATGC")
rna_set = set("AUGC")
nucleotide_set = set("ATGCU")

def nuc_ac_check(string):
    str_set = set(string.upper())

    if str_set - nucleotide_set != set():
        return "Not an unambiguous nucleic acid"
    if str_set == rna_set:
        return "RNA"
    if str_set == dna_set:
        return "DNA"
    return "Not DNA or RNA"
```

Answer (score 0):

just asking if the string have `"d"` or `"D"` in it is not good enough to rule out a invalid string, because it may contain `"E"`, `"Z"`, `"X"`, `"1"`, `"@"` or any other possible character, the best solution for this in my opinion is to use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) which will reduce anything you give to it to only its distinct elements

for example

```
>>> set("111122222222ddddddddRRRRRRRDDDDD")
{'D', '1', 'd', '2', 'R'}
>>>
```

then you only need to compare against the set of valid option to see if there is any match

```
RNA = set("ACGU")
DNA = set("ACGT")

def nuc_ac_check(string):
    d_r_na = set(string.upper())

    if d_r_na == DNA:
        return "DNA"
    elif d_r_na == RNA:
        return "RNA"
    else:
        return "not an unambiguous nucleotide"


Rna_seq = "GGUACGGCUUGGUAUCCCACUCAGUGGCACCUGUGGCCU"
peptide_seq= "acgsdtushnsdses"
Dna_seq = "ggatacgatc"

print('the rna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Rna_seq))
print('the peptide seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(peptide_seq))
print('the Dna seq variable is: ' + nuc_ac_check(Dna_seq))
```

and the output is

```
the rna seq variable is: RNA
the peptide seq variable is: not an unambiguous nucleotide
the Dna seq variable is: DNA
```